# Need help finding the correct regex pattern for my string pattern

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing, split

I'm terrible with RegEx patterns, and I'm writing a simple python program that requires splitting lines of a file into a 'content' part and a 'tags' part, and then further splitting the tags parts into individual tags. Here's a simple example of what one line of my file might look like:

`The Beatles <music,rock,60s,70s>`

I've opened my file with begun reading lines like this:

```
def Load(self, filename):
    file = open(filename, r)

    for line in file:
        #Ignore comments and empty lines..
        if not line.startswith('#') and not line.strip():
        #...
```

Forgive my likely terrible Python, it's my first few days with the language. Anyway, next I was thinking it would be useful to use a regex to break my string into sections - with a variable to store the 'content' (for example, "The Beatles"), and a list/set to store each of the tags. As such, I need a regex (or two?) that can:

- Split the raw part from the <> part.
- And split the tags part into a list based on the commas.
- Finally, I want to make sure that the content part retains its capitalization and inner spacing. But I want to make sure the tags are all lower-case and without white space.

I'm wondering if any of the regex experts out there can help me find the correct pattern(s) to achieve my goals here?

Comment: Not an RE expert, but something like this seems to be what you're after: '([^<]*)<([^>]*)>' if you're using strip() to remove whitespace at each end of the line. 

This should match strings like your example with two groups containing everything left of the first '<' character (i.e. "The Beatles ") and everything contained between the '<' and '>' characters (i.e. "music,rock,60s,70s").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution that gets around the problem without using by relying on multiple splits.

```
# This separates the string into the content and the remainder
content, tagStr = line.split('<')

# This splits the tagStr into individual tags. [:-1] is used to remove trailing '>'
tags = tagStr[:-1].split(',')

print content
print tags
```

The problem with this is that it leaves a trailing whitespace after the content.
You can remove this with:

```
content = content[:-1]
```

Comment: You can use multi-char split separator like this:
`content, tagStr = line.split(' <')`
In this case trailing space after band name is treated as a part of the separator and doesn't contaminate data. That, of course, is assuming no chars other than space are used here (which is rather reasonable).